# reactjs/redux + django CSRF protection

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, react-redux, csrf-protection

I am trying to make an AJAX request from my `reactjs` frontend to my `django` backend but I am getting this error upon POST. I'm not sure how to properly pass CSRF tokens around for my form POST to work properly

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /api/contact
[05/Nov/2016 03:43:14] "POST /api/contact HTTP/1.1" 403 2502
```

I created a react component and added it into my form

CSRF component

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = $.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

const Csrf = () => {
    let csrfToken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    return (
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={ csrfToken } />
    );
};

export default Csrf;
```

Contact form component:

```
const ContactForm = ({ formOnChange, onFormSubmit, isFullNameValid, isEmailValid, isMsgValid }) => {
    let rows = 10;
    let tabindex = 8;
    let isSubmitDisabled = !(isFullNameValid && isEmailValid && isMsgValid);

    return(
        <div className="form-wrapper">
            <form className="contact-form" onChange={ formOnChange }>
                <Csrf />
                <input className={ isFullNameValid ? "" : "active" } type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name *"  />
                <div className="email-phone-group">
                    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
                    <input className={ isEmailValid ? "" : "active" } type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email *"/>
                </div>
                <textarea className={ isMsgValid ? "" : "active" } rows={ rows } tabIndex={ tabindex } name="message" placeholder="Message... *"/>
                <button disabled={ isSubmitDisabled } className="contact-form-submit-btn" type="button" onClick={ onFormSubmit }>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};
```

My redux action calls this AJAX function

```
export function contactSubmission(contactSubmission) {
    // thunk
    return dispatch => {
        console.log("contact form submitted");
        console.log(contactSubmission);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/contact',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: payload => {
                if (payload.error) {
                    return dispatch(contactSubmissionFailure());
                } else {
                    return dispatch(contactSubmissionSuccess(payload));
                }
            },
            error: payload => {
                console.log("ajax error");
                console.log(payload);
                return dispatch(contactSubmissionFailure());
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put the following code before $.ajax to send a CSRF code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")}
            });
```

...THEN YOUR CODE

```
$.ajax({...});
```

You can notice that you have already set getCookie.

With this should work properly.